# Which video format/codecs should I use for HTML <video> to support actual most recent major browsers?

Tags: html, html5-video, video-codecs

I see other questions addressing the same subject:

- [What HTML5 video codecs should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539553/what-html5-video-codecs-should-be-used)
- [Which video and audio format/codec should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589614/which-video-and-audio-format-codec-should-i-use)

But they are old and on this subject having updated information I think is crucial.

I am using now `video/webm;codecs=vp9` but I am having problems with some browsers

So what format(s)/codec(s) versions of my video should I offer to support the last version of the major browsers in Windows, Linux, Mac, Android and iOS?

I am generating the video in the browser it self using MediaRecorder so if the suggested format(s)/codec(s) can be generated using this system this will save me the extra step to re-encode it on the server.

If you have a `ffmpeg` command configuration to generate the format(s)/codec(s) this will also help me.

Comment: have a look at the "sub-features" on https://caniuse.com/video for the various supported codecs/containers and their current support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Offbeatmammal suggested on [his/her comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296514/which-video-format-codecs-should-i-use-for-html5-video-today?noredirect=1#comment124347886_70296514), we can see the actual compatibility for the video codecs here:

- https://caniuse.com/?search=video

But the amount of information there is huge and difficult to digest in a specific answer.

Our friends from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs#recommendations_for_everyday_videos) have some specific suggestions to make and I hope they are updated:

- A WebM container using the VP9 codec for video and the Opus codec for audio
- An MP4 container and the AVC (H.264) video codec, ideally with AAC as your audio codec

Result:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp9, opus"'>
  <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1, aac"'>    
</video>
```

These are the `ffmpeg` most basic configurations to generate such files:

```
# Webm
ffmpeg -i #INPUT -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus video.webm

# MP4
ffmpeg -i #INPUT -c:v libx264 -c:a aac video.mp4
```

Comment: `avc1` is not a valid codec. Try to console log `MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1"')`

Same goes for `aac` too

Comment: `aac` is a valid codec string. but i dont know why `MediaSource.isTypeSupported` returned false for it

Answer (score 0):

If mime codec is unknown, and if quality doesn't matter to you and all you want is to just present the audio/video, here's a function i have written that might help

```js
const getDefaultCodec = mimeType => {
  const codecMap = {
    'video/webm': 'vp9',
    'audio/webm': 'opus',
    'video/mp4': 'avc1.42001E',
    'audio/mp4': 'mp4a.40.2',
  }

  return codecMap[mimeType] || ''
}

export const getDefaultCodecMime = mimeType => {
  const codec = getDefaultCodec(mimeType)
  if (codec) return `${mimeType}; codecs="${codec}"`
  else return mimeType
}
```